# Copy certificate from website and add it to trusted root authority using script

Tags: c++, powershell, certificate

I need to copy a certificate from a website to a file and then import that certificate in trusted root authority.

To import the certificate to trusted root authority I am using following C++ Code:

```
SYSTEM("certutil -addstore -f -enterprise -user root D:\certificateName.cer");
```

Is there any way to copy certificate from given website say https://mywebsite.tryingcertificate.com to location `D:\certificateName.cer` ?

I am stuck with this step. I need to copy and install certificate programmatically for my C++ App.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

To get certificate from website you can use following `PowerShell` script:

```
$request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create('https:\\google.com')
$request.GetResponse().Dispose()
$bytes = $request.ServicePoint.Certificate.Export('Cert')
$bytes | Set-Content D:\certificateName.cer -Encoding Byte
```